# Rudin 3.6 - convergence of subsequences in compact metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading through Baby Rudin and I'm slightly confused about Theorem 3.6 (a).

The theorem is as follows:

$\textbf{ If $\{ p_n\}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space $X$,}$$\textbf{ then some subsequence of $\{ p_n\}$ converges to a point of $X$}$.

The main point of confusion for me is I'm not seeing how this is different than Theorem 2.37, stated in the previous chapter, which reads as follows:

$\textbf{If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$. }$

My thinking on it is that any subsequence in a compact metric space, or a compact set (which I believe may be regarded as the same), is by definition an infinite subset of a compact metric space. Indeed, even in the proof of Theorem 3.6 (a), where Rudin considers the case that the range of $\{ p_n\}$ is infinite, he refers back to Theorem 2.37.

However, I feel as if I'm missing something because if I've learned anything, is that Rudin is not one to write anything superfluous, so if it was the same, it certainly wouldn't be restated.

But ya, why is it even necessary to consider the separate cases of the range of $\{ p_n\}$ being finite and infinite, and what exactly is the difference between these two statements?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Limit point of set and subsequential limit of a sequence is not the same concept. Consider a constant sequence. Its range is a singleton, hence has no limit point. But the sequence converges, and in particular a subsequence converges to the limit. Also, a set may be uncountable, in which case the set cannot be written as a range of some sequence.

Comment: Ohh ok! I understand your first point. However for the 2nd, wouldn't any compact set by definition be countable, as there is some finite open covering which contains it? So a limit point of the set should be able to be written as a range of some sequence no?

Comment: No. 'Finite subcovering' means there are finite sets $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ that covers whole space, but each $U_i$ may be uncountable(which is the case for classic examples such as closed interval $[a, b]$).

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I understand each U_i may be uncountable, but my point is simply that we can extract a countable subset from each U_i to construct a sequence that converges. So for [0,1], whatever the open cover may be, I can describe any limit point, say 0 for example, by taking the countable subset {1/n: n in Naturals}. So theoretically, any limit point in a compact set can be written as a countable subsequence. In that sense they are equivalent. Maybe I'm, misunderstanding the point about why the compact set being uncountable matters for describing limit points.

Comment: Yes. To prove their equivalence you can argue like that. But I am just pointing out that they are not `immediately' equivalent. Your argument can be used to prove Theorem 3.6(a) using Theorem 2.37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the case when $\{p_n\}$ is infinite, and let's call this set $E$. If this subset has a limit point in $K$, it means there is a point $y \in K$ and  a sequence of points $p_{i_1}, p_{i_2},p_{i_3},\cdots$ converging to $y$. However, this sequence may not be a subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ because we cannot assume that the indices are increasing, i.e. $i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \cdots$. This explains the difference: Theorem 2.37 says that you can find some sequence in $E$ that converges, but a sequence in $E$ is not the same thing as a subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ due to the order of the indices.

Comment: Ahh I see so it's essentially just saying that if there is a limit point we can theoretically customly assign each $p_i$ that meets the criteria of being a lesser distance from the limit point an increasing index, and thus construct a subsequence?

Comment: If the set has a limit point, the sequence of points in $E$ you construct to reach it may have no relationship to the original order of $\{p_n\}$, and so won't give you a subsequence thereof. You need to use a different approach when trying to obtain a subsequence.